# restart Akka actor from supervising actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have a set of devices which run a TCP server. In my app I want to maintain a single TCP connection for each device. To recover from failure, each connection is a supervised Akka actor, started from a central actor: `TcpClientManager`.

I also want to restart such a connection from a REST call, no matter its current context.

That's why I want to restart it from within the parent actor, which is the TcpClientManager` actor.  It seems that from within this context, I can only stop the *supervising* actor. Is that correct? How should restart the underlying actor?

```
class TcpClientManager(devices: Seq[Device]) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var idToActor = Map.empty[String, ActorRef]

  override def preStart(): Unit =
    devices(device => {

      val tcpClientProps =
        TcpClient.props(device)

      val tcpClientSupervisorActor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
        Backoff.onStop(
          childProps = tcpClientProps,
          childName = s"tcpCient-${device.id}",
          minBackoff = 1 seconds,
          maxBackoff = 5 seconds,
          randomFactor = 0.2,
          maxNrOfRetries = -1
        ))

      idToActor += device.id -> context.actorOf(
        tcpClientSupervisorActor,
        name = s"tcpClientSupervisorActor-${device.id}")
      })

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case ResetConnection(id) => {
      println(s"reset connection for deviceId  $id")
      idToActor.get(id).foreach(context.stop(_)) // not really... this stops the supervisor
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: context.stop should only stop the targeted actor. Perhaps this expression is failing for some other reason such as accessing the map for an invalid key and thus causing an exception which will lead to the supervisor actor getting stopped

Comment: Maybe you should be firing a tell into the supervising actor instead? Then put logic to reset the connection inside the receive method of the supervising actor.